# ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Nav -> NavController]

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to call a page with push command and i have this problem 
i am using ionic Framework

ts File

```html
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:string = 'AllClientsPage';

  constructor(platform: Platform,public nav: NavController ,statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    storage: Storage) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

     
    });


  }
    goRevervationPage() {

        this.nav.push('ReservationPage  ')
    }
}
```

[this is the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRmLa.png)

App.html

```html
  <ion-content class="sideMenu">
        <ion-list>
            <button class="sideMenuItem selectedItem" ion-item detail-none >Accueil</button>
            <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none (click)="goRevervationPage()">Réservation</button>
            <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none>Créer une fiche client</button>
            <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none>Fiche client</button>
            <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none>All Clients</button>

        </ion-list>
```

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Nav -> NavController]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you use lazy loading for 'ReservationPage' ?

if yes then I think you Just need to remove spaces at the end of 'ReservationPage  '.

```html
goRevervationPage() {
  this.nav.push('ReservationPage');
}
```